# getting Roles that already set to custom Authorization attribute?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-authorization, asp.net-authentication, custom-authentication

I customized the ***authorize*** attribute of Asp.Net but I do not know how to get the roles which I set to the attribute when I set the attribute to a method or class

For example I have this CustomeAuthorizeAttribute

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class CustomeAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {


        if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Super"))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

but I do not know how to get the roles when I set them to the attribute like this

> [CustomeAuthorizeAttribute(Roles="admin,super-admin")]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by default it inhirits the Roles property from the base ***Authorize*** class so you can get the roles directly by using the Roles property

For Example

```
if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole(Roles))
    {
        return true;
    }
```

or you create new properties belong to your custom Authorization attribute and use them.